# Минимальная ширина каждой колонки

Tags: html, css, jquery

Есть такая разметка:

```js
var $table = $('.table');

if ($table.length) {

  var $tr = $table.find('.tr');

  var minWidth = 1;
  $tr.each(function() {
    var $td = $(this).find('.td:nth-of-type(1)');

    $td.each(function() {
      var letWidth = $(this).outerWidth();

      if (letWidth > minWidth) minWidth = letWidth;

    });


  });

  $table.find('.td:nth-of-type(1)').css({
    'width': minWidth
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px 20px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex-positive: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">1</div>
    <div class="td">22222222</div>
    <div class="td">33</div>
    <div class="td">4</div>
    <div class="td">5555</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">7777777777</div>
    <div class="td">88</div>
    <div class="td">9</div>
    <div class="td">100000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">11111111</div>
    <div class="td">22</div>
    <div class="td">3333333</div>
    <div class="td">444</div>
    <div class="td">555</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">77</div>
    <div class="td">88</div>
    <div class="td">9</div>
    <div class="td">1000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">11</div>
    <div class="td">22222</div>
    <div class="td">3333</div>
    <div class="td">444444</div>
    <div class="td">55</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">77777</div>
    <div class="td">8</div>
    <div class="td">9</div>
    <div class="td">100000</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Сейчас вычисляется ширина первой колонки и ширина максимальная.

**Вопрос:** как вычислить **минимальную** ширину каждой ячейки (колонки) для каждой строки и задать ее (независимо от содержания)? Так чтобы колонки в каждой строке совпадали как в таблице.

**!!!** Без задания ширины в стилях для каждой колонки!

Т.е. в первой колонке, например, минимум "1" - ширина там 20px значит у всей колонки столько должно быть. Во второй например "22" и ширина 40px - значит у всей колонки 40px. Надеюсь понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Извиняюсь, что много кода и минимум jQuery... Думаю, что Вы найдёте подходящий вариант:

```js
let aWidth = [], aRulesInd = [];
/* Создание массива исходных размеров ячеек */
$('.tr').each(function(i) {
  aWidth.push([]);
  $(this).find('.td').each(function() {
    aWidth[i].push($(this).outerWidth());
  });
});
/* Исходные размеры */
function fWInitial() {
  if (aRulesInd.length) {
    aRulesInd.reverse().forEach(e => document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule(e)); aRulesInd.length = 0;
  }
}
/* На основе первой строки */
function fWFirstCol() {
  fWInitial();
  aWidth[0].forEach((e, i) => {
    aRulesInd[i] = document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(`.td:nth-child(${i + 1}) { min-width: ${e}px; max-width: ${e}px; }`, 0);
  });
}
/* Одинаковый максимум */
function fWEqualMax() {
  fWInitial();
  aRulesInd.push(document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(`.td { min-width: ${Math.max(...aWidth.flat())}px; }`, 0));
}
/* Одинаковый минимум */
function fWEqualMin() {
  fWInitial();
  aRulesInd.push(document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(`.td { max-width: ${Math.min(...aWidth.flat())}px; }`, 0));
}
/* На основе максимума в колонке */
function fWMaxInCol() {
  fWInitial();
  aWidth[0].forEach((e, i) => {
    aRulesInd[i] = document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(`.td:nth-child(${i + 1}) { min-width: ${Math.max(...aWidth.map(value => value[i]))}px; }`, 0);
  });
}
/* На основе минимума в колонке */
function fWMinInCol() {
  fWInitial();
  aWidth[0].forEach((e, i) => {
    aRulesInd[i] = document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(`.td:nth-child(${i + 1}) { max-width: ${Math.min(...aWidth.map(value => value[i]))}px; }`, 0);
  });
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.tr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px 20px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex-positive: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

.controls { display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; justify-content: space-around; height: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">1</div>
    <div class="td">22222222</div>
    <div class="td">33</div>
    <div class="td">4</div>
    <div class="td">5555</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">7777777777</div>
    <div class="td">88</div>
    <div class="td">9</div>
    <div class="td">100000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">11111111</div>
    <div class="td">22</div>
    <div class="td">3333333</div>
    <div class="td">444</div>
    <div class="td">555</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">77</div>
    <div class="td">88</div>
    <div class="td">9</div>
    <div class="td">1000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">11</div>
    <div class="td">22222</div>
    <div class="td">3333</div>
    <div class="td">444444</div>
    <div class="td">55</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">77777</div>
    <div class="td">8</div>
    <div class="td">9</div>
    <div class="td">100000</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="controls"><label><input onclick="fWInitial()" type="radio" name="variant" checked>Исходные размеры</label><label><input onclick="fWFirstCol()" type="radio" name="variant">На основе первой строки</label><label><input onclick="fWEqualMax()" type="radio" name="variant">Одинаковый максимум</label><label><input onclick="fWEqualMin()" type="radio" name="variant">Одинаковый минимум</label><label><input onclick="fWMaxInCol()" type="radio" name="variant">На основе максимума в колонке</label><label><input onclick="fWMinInCol()" type="radio" name="variant">На основе минимума в колонке</label></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: @HamSter: пожалуйста. Главное условие, чтобы количество ячеек в строках было одинаковое. Строк может быть сколько угодно. При этом, ничего менять не требуется. Возникнут вопросы по данному ответу - отпишитесь здесь.

Answer (score 3):

Без jQuery

```js
function calcLengthTd(table) {
  const allTr = table.querySelectorAll('.tr');
  let lastLength = 0;
  
  for (tr of allTr) {
    const lengthTd = tr.querySelectorAll('.td').length;
    
    if (lastLength < lengthTd) {
      lastLength = lengthTd;
    }
  }
  return lastLength;
}

function calcMaxWidth(elems) {

  let maxWidth = 0;

  for (item of elems) {
    if (item.offsetWidth > maxWidth) {
      maxWidth = item.offsetWidth;
    }
  }
  return maxWidth;

}

function addMinWidth(table, lengthTd, maxWidth) {
  
  for (let i = 0; i < lengthTd; i++) {
    const td_s_Column = table.querySelectorAll(`.tr .td:nth-of-type(${i + 1})`);
    const maxWidth = calcMaxWidth(td_s_Column); // посчитать максимальную ширину для блоков в колонке
    
    for (td of td_s_Column) {
      td.style.minWidth = maxWidth + 'px';
    }
  }
  
}

const table = document.querySelector('.table');
const lengthTd = calcLengthTd(table); // количество колонок

addMinWidth(table, lengthTd);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.td {
  padding: 2px 20px;
}

.table .td:nth-of-type(n) {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.table .tr:nth-of-type(1) .td {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.table .td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">1</div>
    <div class="td">22222222</div>
    <div class="td">33</div>
    <div class="td">4</div>
    <div class="td">5555</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">7777777777</div>
    <div class="td">88</div>
    <div class="td">9</div>
    <div class="td">100000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">11111111</div>
    <div class="td">22</div>
    <div class="td">3333333</div>
    <div class="td">444</div>
    <div class="td">555</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">77</div>
    <div class="td">88</div>
    <div class="td">9</div>
    <div class="td">1000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">11</div>
    <div class="td">22222</div>
    <div class="td">3333</div>
    <div class="td">444444</div>
    <div class="td">55</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">77777</div>
    <div class="td">8</div>
    <div class="td">9</div>
    <div class="td">100000</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: одинаковая для каждой колонки , не для всех колонок одна ширина и минимальная. Т.е. в первой колонке минимум "1" - ширина там 20px значит у всей колонки столько должно быть. Во второй например "22" и ширина 40px - значит у всей колонки 40 ))) надеюсь понятно

Comment: @HamSter понял, сейчас буду думать

Comment: @HamSter поправил, вроде